# Remote USB Dongle 'Reseating'?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

We run a (VectorWorks) License Server software on a Windows 10 VM, hosted on an OSX Mac Mini with USB License Dongle attached.

If the WINDOWS VM crashes, or the OSX mac, everything comes back up ok or via remote assistance, except for the USB dongle. It is not recognised until it is removed and re-inserted manually. This requires physical presence in the Server Room.

1. Does anyone also see this issue on a native Windows PC? If not, I will look into installing Windows 10 on the Mac Mini or another small PC.
2. Does anyone know a way to remotely 'reseat' a USB dongle?!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a usual problem - it can most often be solved by removing the USB passthrough in your virtualization software and reenabling it.